# Proper way to remove Gruntjs, package.json and other files from release branch

Tags: wordpress, git, git-flow

I am developing a wordpress theme. I am new to using Grunt and composer for packages.

I have also integrated git flows. At the moment I am developing on develop branch and then merge to master once I am satisfied with the code.

The problem I am facing is that my master branch has Gruntfile.js as well as package.json in it. Similarly there are sass files in css folders. I want a clean release branch, in which there are only required theme files and no gruntjs, pacakge.json and sass files.

These all files are being tracked in master, how can I create a clean release branch.

I have followed the [Woocommerce repository](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce) for making my development environment. 
I could not find a build process in it also. Am I missing any proper step?

P.S : I don't know if I should be sharing any code samples here, but if you want anything I can share it here.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware you can't do what you're trying to do and I don't believe git is meant to work that way. Having your grunt & SASS files in the master branch is the correct way of doing this, those files are also in the Woocommerce repository you've linked to.

I'm guessing what you're trying to do is create a release of a theme that doesn't have any of the 'development only files', for lack of a better term, to give to the the end user installing the theme? If so that release would be a separate 'thing' to git as git is mainly for developer version control. What I think you're after is just creating a stand-alone downloadable zip file by the sounds of things?

For example if you were to [submit your theme to WordPrss.org they take it as a zip file](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/release/submitting-your-theme-to-wordpress-org/) rather than a link to a git repository.